# $T$ is a linear operator, with $T^2=Id$. Is $T$ necessarily normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm stuck with this question. I do believe the claim is correct but I don't know how to show it.

If we know that $T^2=Id$, then $T=T^{-1}$on the one hand, and on the other hand we know that $T^2$ is orthogonal, hence $(T^2)^*=(T^2)^{-1}$ which implies that $(T^{-1})^2=(T^*)^2$. I can't find the way to take it to the next step and show that $T^{-1}=T^*$ to get that $T$ is also orthogonal, nor am I able to conclude anything about $T, T^*$'s commutativity.

Comment: Of course not, one can find counterexamples in 2x2 matrices.

Comment: Really? Can you help me with that? I wasn't able to come up with any.

Comment: OK, I give you one, it corresponds to the symmetry w.r.t the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, one can find counterexamples in 2x2 matrices.

Take 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2\cr
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
This is the symmetry w.r.t the line $y=x$ (anti-invariant) across $x=0$ (invariant). It sends $I\to I;\ I+J\to -(I+J)$.

One can prove that ($T^2=I$ and $T$ normal) implies ($T$ is an orthogonal symmetry). Then if you take any symmetry which is not orthogonal, you get a counterexample.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. How did you come up with this example?

Comment: @Noa: Trial and error, perhaps? This is the simplest way to construct a matrix with minimal polynomial $x^2-1$.

Comment: @Noa While I can't speak with certainty on what Duchamp was thinking, if you wanted to create a counterexample, the first step is to have matrices that square to the identity.  These can only have 1 and -1 as eigenvalues, and the easiest way to construct such matrices (and not have them be diagonal, hence symmetric and thus automatically normal) is to make them triangular.  A 2x2 example with a 1 and -1 on the diagonal guarantees that it squares to the identity, and from there it's just a matter of seeing what happens.

Comment: What do you mean by "the symmetry w.r.t the line $y=x$"? The _reflection_ in that line is $(_{1\;0}^{0\;1})$.

Comment: I mean symmetry with the line $x=0$ (invariant) across $x=y$ (anti-invariant).

Comment: @Noa Here is another one way might construct a counterexample.  Again, since $T^2=I$, we have that $T$ must be diagonalizable with eigenvectors in the set $\{1,-1\]$.  Now, we use the characterization that normal matrices are those that are diagonalized by a a unitary matrix.  Therefore, we should take a diagonal matrix and conjugate it by a non-unitary matrix.  However, some problems could occur.  If all our eigenvectors are 1 or all are -1, then conjugation doesn't do anything.  So we conjugate $\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$ by a random non-unitary matrix.  Odds are good that this will work.